# URL was not found on this server

Tags: php, laravel-4, routes

I am using laravel 4.1 with php 5.3.13 but the routing does not work. 
I've made a simple page under views "about.php" and in my routing I added:

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
return View::make('hello');
});

Route::get('about', function()
{
return View::make('about');
});
Route::resource('user', 'userInscriptionController');

 Route::group(array('prefix' => ''), function()
  {
 Route::resource('user', 'userInscriptionController');
 });
```

but only the "hello" page works, the others give me the following message:

```
Not Found
The requested URL /driving/public/about was not found on this server.
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess that you are using apache, if that's the case the AllowOverride Option is set to none so the  .htaccess file that comes with laravel to enable the "pretty url" it's not getting loaded.

Try `http://mywebserver/mylaravelwebsite/index.php/about`

It should work.